# Downgrade Debian PHP package

Tags: php, debian

I have a big problem with my sites after migrate to new server. The only difference is in PHP version.

On old server I have: `5.3.3-7+squeeze15`

On new server is: `5.3.3-7+squeeze17`

Can I migrate from new version to older and how?

OS: Debian 6.0.8

Comment: I dont think this would be the best exchange website to ask it on.

Comment: One way is to compile PHP manually. By the way, PHP version seems the same.. you wrote 5.3.3 for both servers. You probably mean that the server is different version?

Comment: Why do you think this (very minor) difference in versions will be a problem? Have you actually experienced a problem? If so, what?

Answer (score 2):

To specify a specific version of a package to install:

```
sudo apt-get install <package name>=<version number>
```

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install php5=5.3.3-7+squeeze15
```

It may happen that this version is no longer installable, in which case you'd need to fetch it from [the snapshot service](http://snapshot.debian.org), and install it via **dpkg**:

```
sudo dpkg --install <deb filename>
```